# Is there a way to add a counter to a form based on responses?

Tags: google-forms

I'm building a form to collect data from testing water heater station. The operator enters the data every day, but cannot see the number of heaters that have passed. Would be very useful a counter in the input data interface, to take control of the processed equipment.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no built-in feature to add a counter to the form respondent view based on responses, but you could allow the respondents to see the submitted responses. See [View and manage form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)

An alternative could be to allow the form respondent to view the spreadsheet receiving the responses.

It's worth to note that form owner and editors could use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) to edit the form after each response submission, let say to add the number of responses submitted to the Form title or another form element.